# Symfony2 change routing.xml to routing.yml

Tags: php, symfony

I am learning symfony2 been through AcmeBundle and under Resources/config there are two files routing.yml and services.xml i know what they are, my question is when I create my very own Bundle using php app/console cache:clear

I get to choose Configuration format (yml, xml, php or annotation) but by choosing either I always get both routing and services files in the same format.

I would like to always have routing.yml format and services.xml format.

I tried deleting routing.xml and added routing.yml but i can never get this to work....Any help guys

Answer (score 1):

If you change the routing file in your Bundle, you need to tell Symfony to use the new one.
The main routing file is `app/routing.yml` (or `.xml`), and routing files specific to Bundles are loaded from this file.
So, if you want to use YAML files for routing in your Bundles, your `app/routing.yml` should contain something like this:

```
my_bundle:
    resource: "@MyBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml"
    prefix:   /
```

Probably, if you're creating the routing file as XML and then you're just renaming it, your problem is that the `app/routing.yml` is pointing to the wrong file.

That said, I don't really know whether is possible to create the routing file as YAML and the services file in XML and, in fact, I don't think that's a very good idea... you should probably choose the format you like best and stick to it, so everything is more consistent...